# Sencha Touch Audio in Carousel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, html5-audio

I would like to have a small mp3 played every time a new panel is shown in the carousel. I used the audio xtype with autoplay but this results in an cacophony of sounds on startup. The problem occurs on all devices (simulators, Chrome, ipad and nexus7). Now, I use a button that activates the sound but I would like it to autoplay when it is needed (on active panel). It "sounds" so simple but I can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

This is one carousel item (with a button):

```
 {
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',                   
            },
            items: [
                {
                    flex:4,
                    xtype: 'image',
                    src: 'resources/images/hond.png',
                },                                      
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Play',
                    iconCls: 'arrow_right',
                    cls: 'knopsound',
                        handler: function() {
                        Ext.getCmp('hond').toggle();
                        this.setText(Ext.getCmp('hond').isPlaying() ? 'Pause' : 'Play');
                        }
                },
                                    {
                    xtype: 'audio',
                    url: 'resources/images/hond.mp3',

                    id: 'hond',
                    loop: false,
                    enableControls: false,
                    hidden:true
                },

                {
                    flex:3,
                    xtype: 'video',
                    url: 'resources/images/test.mp4',
                    posterUrl: 'resources/images/bekijkgebaar.png',
                    cls: 'videoplayknop',
                    autoResume: true,
                    autoPause: true,
                    enableControls: false,
                }]},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leverage the `activeitemchange(carousel, newItem, oldItem)` event on the carousel to play the sound.

I would just store the url of the sound to play in a custom property of the panel. To do that you could extend `Ext.Panel` and add a custom property in configuration so you'd get getters and setters for that property. Or you could just have an array of sound urls and call the carousel's `getActiveIndex()` to play the right sound.

Once you got the url you would play it using a dummy hidden component:

Something like:

```
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
 '<embed src="' + soundurl + '" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" />';
```

Or if you are developing a native app using Cordova:

```
var media = new Media(url, onSuccess, onFailure);
media.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false });
```

Comment: Thanks Anubis, I got it to work using a listener on the activeitemchange function:       document.getElementById(activeIndex).play();